# Remove white space from GraphicsRow

Tags: graphics, plotting

I am trying to remove as much of the white space above and below the following image produced by:

```
GraphicsRow[{plotA, plotB}, ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {0, 0}}]
```

Resulting in:

[image]

As you can see, there is a lot of white space, above and below the image, which I have tried to remove using ImagePadding, however, to no avail.

Can someone advise me on how to do this?

Best,

Ben

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. Thanks though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
plotA = plotB = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
                ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {None, None}}];
GraphicsRow[{plotA, plotB}, Spacings -> 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or

```
plotA = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
   ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {None, None}}];
plotB = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
   ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {None, None}},
   FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, All}}];
GraphicsRow[{plotA, plotB}, Spacings -> 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's great. Thanks.