# understanding ImagePadding with GraphicsRow (zero padding = missing sides)

Tags: graphics

```
aplot = ArrayPlot[#] & /@ ConstantArray[0, {3, 3, 3}];
GraphicsRow[aplot, ImagePadding -> 0]
```

produces

[image: missing sides]

I see that I can fix this with `ImagePadding ->{{Automatic, Automatic}, {0, 0}}`, but I don't understand why this is needed.  Explanation?

Comment: Why use `ImagePadding` at all?

Comment: To remove whitespace.  See e.g., http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67301/remove-white-space-from-graphicsrow

Comment: It gives me the exact same result as `GraphicsRow[aplot]`, regardless of what's inside.

Comment: @Feyre  I'm using Mma 11 on Win 10.  `ImagePadding` definitely matters for the output (both displayed and saved).

Comment: have you tried `ImageMargins`?

Comment: @george2079 In the question I already provide a solution for the "problem", but I am trying to understand why the problem arises.  That is my question.  E.g., if it is not a bug, what is the logic?

Comment: seems like a bug to me.